# sql del button malfunction

Tags: php, sql, button

Ok, I'm totally new on SQL and didnt even know anything about coding untill a week ago so forgive me if i ask something obvious.

I tried to search on the subject but every answer gives a different solution so i am confused.

Below this button is a iframe autorefreshing my DB on a few seconds.

I try to make a button to delete the first row in my DB and the code works, except it only works when i refresh the page, if i click the button, nothing happens, no row is deleted.

Anyone have a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<input name="input" type="button" onClick="<?php
$servername = "XXXXX";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM XXXXX LIMIT 1;";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>&quot;" value="Kvittera">
```

Comment: You shouldn't embed PHP/MySQL into an input like that, being the reason why it doesn't work. Create a button that calls a function instead.

Comment: is it the delete function i should call for or the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just misunderstanding things. You use PHP as a server-side scripting language. To simplify things, when you ask your web-server to display `index.php`, it processes the contents of `index.php` once, executing everything between `<?` and `?>` and outputting the rest as-is to create a HTML web page which is displayed by your browser. So, when you open the iframe with the code you've pasted in the question, it's executed right away and the row is deleted. If you look to the generated HTML page source code, you'll see something like

```
<input name="input" type="button" onClick="Record deleted successfully&quot;" value="Kvittera">
```

Meanwhile, `onClick` is for *Javascript functions* that execute inside user's browser.
Its just not the way things are done in client-server applications. You'll have to have a separate PHP file that contains a script to delete the row, like `deleterow.php` and call on that file by opening it in a browser like any other link. Now, "opening links" to call scripts like that without actually changing/refreshing the page is done using Javascript AJAX functions, which you can bind to `onClick`. Look it up, it's way too lengthy to describe here.

Comment: So, i did a new indexpage that have a button with no function atm and i autorefreshing iframe below to display the DB. Could anyone, if its not to complicated, give me an example how i should make a script to execute when i press the button? is it something like onClick="script.js" or can i just add the code in a *.txt and call for it?